# When there is a datePicker is selected in ANTD select component, how to let this datePicker be editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

when date-picker selected from dropdown options. I would like the date values of date-picker to be editable in the window once selected. https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-satoshi-ljvqb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: How you want to make it editable ? What action should performed ?

Comment: @Tejas First chose date picker from options and select the date. Allow the date-picker to be editable in the selection box once selected. when you click on the selection box it should be editable for only data-picker item

Comment: Thats what I am asking , I need a method which should open the input->date picker. Can you update fiddle with this method I will update the required code.

Comment: @ Tejas, I have added a method "handleSelect()" in the code sandbox.